# MUI Table body rendered in first cell when wrap table body in Accordion

Tags: javascript, html, material-ui, accordion

Above is my code actually i have data in groups and i need to show each group in a accordion and can have only one header outside the table body when i try the above code then accordion rendered in first cell of table i don not know how i can fix this does anybody can help?

````
        <div>
            <TableContainer
                sx={{ ...classes.tableRoot, ...(customStyleTableContainer || {}) } as SxProps<Theme>}
            >
                <Table stickyHeader>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            {headers?.map((cell: TableHeaderCell, index: number) => (
                                <TableCell
                                    key={`table-header-${index}`}
                                    sx={{
                                        ...tableHeaderCellStyle,
                                        backgroundColor: '#F4F6F8',
                                        padding: '0px'
                                    }}
                                    align={cell.align ?? 'left'}
                                    colSpan={4}
                                >
                                    <Typography variant='subtitle1' color='#212B36' sx={classes.header}>
                                        {cell.label}
                                    </Typography>
                                </TableCell>
                            ))}
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>

                    {dummyData.map((group, index) => (
                        <Accordion
                            key={`accordion-${index}`}
                            expanded={expanded === `panel-${index}`}
                            onChange={toggleAccordion(`panel-${index}`)}
                            disableGutters={true}
                        >
                            <AccordionSummary
                                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                                aria-controls={`panel-${index}-content`}
                                id={`panel-${index}-header`}
                                sx={{ background: 'grey' }}
                            >
                                <Typography variant='subtitle1'>{group.groupName}</Typography>
                            </AccordionSummary>
                            <AccordionDetails>
                                <TableBody>
                                    {group.data.map((row, rowIndex) => (
                                        <TableRow key={`row-${rowIndex}`}>
                                            {Object?.entries(row).map(
                                                ([key, value], index: number) =>
                                                    key !== 'id' && (
                                                        <TableCell
                                                            key={`table-cell-${index}`}
                                                            sx={{ padding: '0px' }}
                                                            colSpan={4}
                                                        >
                                                            {value}
                                                        </TableCell>
                                                    )
                                            )}
                                        </TableRow>
                                    ))}
                                </TableBody>
                            </AccordionDetails>
                        </Accordion>
                    ))}
                </Table>
            </TableContainer>
        </div>
    );```
````